# downgrade php5.6 to php5.5

Tags: php, ubuntu, downgrade

I am trying to downgrade my php version from 5.6 to 5.6 here is what I have tried so far :

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
apt-get update
apt-cache policy php5
```

the output the last command was :

```
installé : 5.6.11+dfsg-lubuntu3.1
candidat : 5.6.11+dfsg-lubuntu3.1
```

I expected the output to be something like 5.5 as I added old php        repository.
things like :

```
apt-get install php5=5.5.24
```

did not work either.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you remove 5.6 first?

Comment: From 5.6 to 5.6? That's a downgrade! ;)

Comment: yes I ran the command apt-get --purge remove php*

Comment: I also removed apache so that only nginx is left.